# Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Firestore backend code where I'm trying to add a subscription using an HTTP Cloud Function. The function is triggered by an HTTP request, and I retrieve the email value from the request body. When testing the function with Postman and passing the request body as {"email":"xapoxa14@gmail.com"}, everything works correctly, and the subscription is added successfully. However, when I send the same request from my frontend application, I receive the following error:

> Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

It seems that the email value from the request.body sometimes becomes undefined. I have confirmed that the email field is present and correctly formatted in the request body sent from the frontend.

Here is a snippet of my backend code:

```
export const addSubscription = https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  corsHandler(request, response, async () => {
    const { email } = request.body;
    console.log(request.body);

    try {
      const subscriptionsRef = connection.collection("Subscriptions");
      const subscriptionQuerySnapshot = await subscriptionsRef.where("email", "==", email).get();
      const isSubscribed = !subscriptionQuerySnapshot.empty;

      if (!isSubscribed) {
        await subscriptionsRef.add({ email });
      }

      response.status(200).send("Subscription added successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).send(`${error}`);
    }
  });
});
```

I find it puzzling why the email value sometimes becomes undefined only when executing the Firestore query through the frontend application, while it works correctly when using Postman. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing the code from your frontend that invokes this function, there's not much we can help with.  I think it's pretty clear that the frontend is just not passing a value for email. You should check for that in the function code and return a meaningful error to the client.